# Area of $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Could you tell me how to calculate the area of part of the plane:  $\frac{x}{a} + \frac{y}{b} + \frac{z}{c} = 1$, $a, b, c >0$ where all coordinates of a point are positive?

Comment: the other, less exciting, way to solve this is to solve for $z$ and find the surface area of the resulting graph over the appropriate triangular region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: solve for when $2$ of $x,y,$ and $z$ are $0$. This will give you the $3$ coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which are the vertices of the triangle you are looking for.

Comment: So the triangle has vertices $A = (a,0,0), B=(0,b,0), C=(0,0,c)$. Vector $BA = (-a, b,0), BC=(0,b,-c)$. So the area seems to be $\sqrt{a^2b^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2}$. I'll check if Heron's formula gives the same result in a moment.

Comment: Ok, Heron's formula gives the same solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a triangle. Find the vectors along two sides and use the relation which connects vectors and the area of the triangle which they border. In particular, if $v,w$ are the vectors along the side then $\frac{1}{2}|v \times w|$ is the area. So, find those vectors. Hint: $x=y=0$ for $v$ and $y=z=0$ for $w$.